# Hive XML SerDe - Add a constant value in column

Tags: xml, xpath, hive, hive-serde

I have a Hive table like below..I would like have the first column to be a constant value (Its not coming in the XML file).  if I hardcode the value, its not being displayed when I do a select on the table... what am I doing wrong?
I tried using the concatenate operator also (with dummy xpath and adding the string)...still no luck
...any help is appreciated..

`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS raw_RMS_20170629(
SourceSystem STRING,
Account  STRING,
Action STRING,
AllocationType STRING,
AlternativeTradeId STRING,
...
...
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.SourceSystem"="RMS",
"column.xpath.Account"="Trade/Account/text()",
"column.xpath.Action"="Trade/Action/text()",
"column.xpath.AllocationType"="Trade/AllocationType/text()",
...
...
```

Sample Data below.  The external table is created dynamically everytime oozie workflow runs and I would like to add a constant field (sourcesystem = RMS or.. GSS etc when I create the table)

`<queryReply>
    <Trade xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rms="http://www.example.org/store/schema/abc/durables/rms" 
    xmlns:rms-raw="http://www.example.org/td/tm/lite/rms-raw/v1.0">
        <Account>AKA</Account>
        <Action xsi:nil="true"/>
        <AllocationType xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TradeId>
            <rms:SYSTEMID>97926437</rms:SYSTEMID>
        </TradeId>
        <TradeVersion>
            <rms:VERSION>1</rms:VERSION>
        </TradeVersion>
        <InstrumentId xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TraderSourceSystemName xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TraderId xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TraderName xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TraderEmail xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TradeStatus>Open</TradeStatus>
        ...
        ...
        <Currency/>
        <UnderlyingCurrency>
            <UNDERCURRENCY>USD</UNDERCURRENCY>
        </UnderlyingCurrency>
        <ExpiryDate xsi:nil="true"/>
        <FuturesExpiryDate xsi:nil="true"/>
        <FutureSubType xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CashBalance xsi:nil="true"/>
        <FutureCode xsi:nil="true"/>
        <UnderlyingExchange xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CorrelationId xsi:nil="true"/>
    </Trade>
    </queryReply>`

Comment: Add a data sample

Comment: Thank you, Mark.  Updated the original post with sample data

Comment: My use case is to add a constant column (which is not available in XML) to the create table script, so when I do a select on the table, it gets displayed with the constant (in the above case, the column is sourcesystem with value RMS)

Comment: Hi Markovitz, do you know if its possible to add constant as a column in a dynamic Hive table (that maps to XML)

Comment: I have tried, so far without success... :-)

Comment: @Markovitz, Thank you

Comment: A work-around could be wrapping the table with a view that included an hard-coded column